# Chrome WebDriver hungs when currently selected frame closed

Tags: selenium, tinymce, webdriver, frame, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on creation of automated test for some Web Application. This application is very complex. In fact it is text editor for specific content. As a part of functionality it has some pop-up frames. You may open this pop-up? make some changes and save them - closing current frame. May problem is in that fact, that close button situated inside frame will be eliminating. And this force Chrome WebDriver to hung. My first try was like this:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='insert']")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

But it hungs on first line after executinh click command as this command close frame.
Then I change to this(I have JQuery on the page):

```
    driver.executeScript("$(\"input#insert\").click()");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

But this leads to same result.
Then I use this solution:

```
    driver.executeScript("setTimeout(function(){$(\"input#insert\").click()}, 10)");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

And it hungs on second line. Only this solution works:

```
    driver.executeScript("setTimeout(function(){$(\"input#insert\").click()}, 100)");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

but only if you don't take into account, that it is unstable - some timing issue may occur.

So may question is there more cleaner and more stable way for switch out from closed frame?

P.S.: executeScript - self defined function to decrease amount of code. It simply executer some js on page.

Update:

I realized I was wrong. This problem is not for all iframes. It's occur when tinyMCE popup used. Situation is exactly like in [this topic](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2703). So it's doubtful I will find answer here, but who knows. Solution described above will help, but only for very short amount of time, meaning that after several seconds pass chromedriver will hangs on next command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in this line of tinyMCEPopup code:

```
   DOM.setAttrib(id + '_ifr', 'src', 'javascript:""'); // Prevent leak
```

Executing this script on page fix hang problem(but possibly creates leaks :) ):

```
(function() {
var domVar;
if (window.tinymce && window.tinymce.DOM) {
    domVar = window.tinymce.DOM 
}
else if (window.tinyMCE && window.tinyMCE.DOM) {
    domVar = window.tinyMCE.DOM 
}
else {
    return;
}
var tempVar = domVar.setAttrib;console.log(123)
domVar.setAttrib = function(id, attr, val) {
    if (attr == 'src' && typeof(val)== 'string' &&(val + "").trim().match(/javascript\s*:\s*("\s*"|'\s*')/)) {
        console.log("Cool");
        return;
    }
    else {
        tempVar.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

}());
```

Bug and solution also described [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2703)
Note. Code above should be added to parent frame, not into popup frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it in Ruby, hopefully you can change it for java

```
$driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@id='insert']").click
$wait.until {$driver.window_handles.size < 2} #this will "explicitly wait" for the window to close
handles = $driver.window_handles #get available window handles
$driver.switch_to.window(handles[0]) #navigate to default in this case the First window handle
```

hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, description of the pronblem wasn't full.